# Export json data (bulk data) to excel and download in .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, excel, httphandler

I have an asp.net application. It has a JavaScript file and an `ashx` file.

The download button has a click event that:

- calls a handler file in ajax call, and
- retrieves sql table data in a json formatted string, and
- returns to the ajax success method.
- export to excel and download.

I am trying to export the json formated string to an  excel or csv file and download it.

I tried `<http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/>?` but it supports only small data.

If the data from the sql table is large that code won't help.

How can I handle large amounts of data?

Comment: Please help me to find some easy and helpful javascript/jquery libaries/plugin to create Excel files (xls,xlsx) from json format data.